# recursive method for finding maximum subvector

Tags: c++, algorithm

here is    recursive  code     for finding   maximum subvector sum

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Max(int a,int b,int c){
    return max(a,std::max(b,c));
}
int a[]={31,-41,59,26,-53,58,97,-93,-23,84};
int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
int maximum3(int l,int u){
    if (l>u) return 0;
    if (l==u) return std::max(0,a[l]);

    int m=(l+u)/2;
    int lmax=0;
    int sum=0;
    int rmax=0;
    int sum1=0;
    for (int i=m;i>=l;i--){
        sum+=a[i];
        lmax=std::max(lmax,sum);
    }
    for (int j=m+1;j<u;j++){
        sum1+=a[j];
        rmax=std::max(rmax,sum);
    }

    return Max(lmax+rmax,maximum3(l,m),maximum3(m+1,u));
}

int main(){
    cout<<maximum3(0,n-1)<<"  ";
    return 0;
}
```

it rerurns  155 while other non recursive method returns 187  please help

Comment: Basic debugging: although you've identified what you expect, and what you actually get, you haven't taken any steps to narrow the problem down.  Trace through the program, either with printf, a debugger, or by hand, and you will see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 5):

**@user466411**:  You have asked **274** questions in the last 7 months, or roughly a question every single day.   Many of these questions have been **[Closed]**, received serious negative votes **[-5 or more]**, or both.

This pattern indicates clearly: 
**You need to re-think how you approach programming**.

- You need to learn to use a debugger.
- You need to narrow down large problems to specific issues.
- You need to precisely describe problems.
- You need to test pieces of code before combining them into larger elements.
- You need to attempt fixes, observe the effects, hypothesize solutions and test them.

All in all,  you are programming ***wrong***.
Most new programmers can master elementary programming in far less than 7 months without daily hand-holding. Either you need to approach programming anew, learning fresh how to think about code, or you need to acknowledge that programming is not for you, and you should find a new line of work.

*(to other commenters: yes, I know this answer is non-responsive to this question, but it desperately needed to be said; see my other post for a responsive answer, trying to guide poster to a solution)*

Comment: thank you. You might add some SO specific advice like "don't create duplicate questions for the same issue" and "pay closer attention to code formatting".

Answer (score 1):

Typo, this:

```
rmax=std::max(rmax,sum);
```

should be

```
rmax=std::max(rmax,sum1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code I wrote and tested correct. Thought it might be useful...

```
#include <iostream.h>

void findMaxCrossSubArray(int a[], int low, int mid, int high, int crossCur[])
{
    int leftSum = -9999;
    int sum = 0;
    int maxLeft, maxRite;

    maxLeft = maxRite = 0;

    for (int i = mid; i >=  low; i--)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    if (sum > leftSum)
    {
        leftSum = sum;
        maxLeft = i;
    }
    }
    int riteSum = -9999;
    sum = 0;
    for (int j = mid + 1; j <= high; j++)
    {
        sum += a[j];
        if (sum > riteSum)
    {
        riteSum = sum;
        maxRite = j;
    }
    }
    crossCur[0] = maxLeft;
    crossCur[1] = maxRite;
    crossCur[2] = leftSum + riteSum;
    return;
} 

void findMaxSubArray (int a[], int low, int high, int curMax[])
{
    if (high == low)
    {
        curMax[0] = low;
    curMax[1] = high;
    curMax[2] = a[low];
    return;
    }

    int mid = (low + high)/2;

    int leftCur[3], riteCur[3], crossCur[3];
    findMaxSubArray(a, low, mid, leftCur);
    findMaxSubArray(a, mid+1, high, riteCur);
    findMaxCrossSubArray(a, low, mid, high, crossCur);

    if ((leftCur[2] >= riteCur[2]) && (leftCur[2] >= crossCur[2]))
    {
        curMax[0] = leftCur[0];
    curMax[1] = leftCur[1];
    curMax[2] = leftCur[2];
    return;
    }
    if ((riteCur[2] >= leftCur[2]) && (riteCur[2] >= crossCur[2]))
    {
        curMax[0] = riteCur[0];
    curMax[1] = riteCur[1];
    curMax[2] = riteCur[2];
    return;
    }

    curMax[0] = crossCur[0];
    curMax[1] = crossCur[1];
    curMax[2] = crossCur[2];
    return;
}   

int main()
{
    int a[] = {13, -3, -25, 20, -3, -16, -23, 18, 20,-7, 12, -5, -22, 15, -4, 7};
    int curMax[] = {0,0,0};

    findMaxSubArray(a, 0, 15, curMax);

    cout << curMax[0] << "," << curMax[1] << "," << curMax[2] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Where do you think the maximum subvector sum is, that generates the answer 187?**
*I believe it is the sequence: `[59, 26, -53, 58, 97]`.*

**Which subvector sum generates your answer of 155?**
*I believe it is the sequence: `[58, 97]`.*

**Why does your algorithm not pickup on the larger subvector sum?**
Thats a darn good question.  You can answer it yourself with basic debugging techniques.

At the end of the first call, your `LMax` should be 22, your `RMax` should be 123, and the `TotalSum` should be 145 *(found by tracing the program by hand)*.   Do you agree?

**What does the 2nd call to maximum3 generate?**